# Add another item/row on form, insert into DB

Tags: php, mysql

[image: add another item]

These two fields are inserted into a database. However, I want to give the user the ability to "Add another item". They should be able to, ideally, add as many items as they like. When they submit the form, the data would be inserted into a mysql table.

How can I go about doing this? Creating 10 extra columns in my database to accommodate extra items being added does not sound realistic nor ideal.

Thanks for the help!

Here is a snippet of my code, where I insert my data into the DB:

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT items (number, description) VALUES (?, ?)"))
                            {
                                    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $number, $description);
                                    $stmt->execute();
                                    $stmt->close();
                            }
```

Comment: your code ? can you post it on jsfiddle ?

Comment: creating extra columns in your db? You are certainly doing something wrong, search for some 'database normalization' tutorials

Comment: @WouterJ I'm a bit new to mysql. Will take a look at some tutorials. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use :

```
name="item[]"
```

for item # '

and

```
name="description[]"

<input type="text" name="item[]" /><input type="text" name="description[]" />
```

For item description field and in your server side iterate through both of them.
in the front end just create a script that duplicate that node many times.

**EDIT**

Based in the code you showed it should be something similar to the below code :

```
if(isset($_POST['item']){
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['item']); $i++){
$number = $_POST['item'][$i];
$description= $_POST['description'][$i];
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT items (number, description) VALUES (?, ?)"))
                            {
                                    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $number, $description);
                                    $stmt->execute();
                                    $stmt->close();
                            }
}
```

In your javascript do like below:

```
function addRow(){
  document.getELementById('container').el.innerHTML += '<input type="text" name="item[]" /><input type="text" name="description[]" />' ;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<form name='myform' >

 <div id="container">
 <input type="text" name="item[]" /><input type="text" name="description[]" />     
 </div>
    <p onclick="addRow() ;" >Add another item</p>
</form>
```

I hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

Try this one :

```
if(isset($_POST['item']){

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT items (number, description) VALUES (?, ?)"))
{
  for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['item']); $i++){
  $number = $_POST['item'][$i];
  $description= $_POST['description'][$i];

                                    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $number, $description);
                                    $stmt->execute();

  }
  $stmt->close();

 }
```

Comment: If I do not have another item, it works fine. But if I add more items, I get `Warning: mysqli::prepare() [mysqli.prepare]: Couldn't fetch mysqli` for each additional item added. One item is added into the database, but any additional items are NOT and receive the error mentioned.

Comment: @Alex Try the on in the UPDATE that I just added.

Comment: How would I go about adding an "id" variable to this?

Comment: @Alex adding an `id` to your table ?

Comment: Adding an `id` along with each row inserted into the table, yes. The ID should be the same for each item added at the same time. So if I inserted 2 items, then both items should have the same `id`

Comment: in the database an id (or a primary key) should be unique, in your case you probably need a composite key, like `operation_id, item_id` so for example you will have for `operation_id = 1` and you insert two items you will have `item_id = 1` and `item_id = 2` so : `1,1` and `1,2` as keys in your tale.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26204/discussion-between-alex-and-mehdi-karamosly)

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty complex question, but there are some pretty straightforward solutions. First off, you'll need to change the back-end PHP script that you use to handle having a variable number of items.

For example, right now, you probably have something like:

```
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$item_description = $_POST['item_description'];
add_item_to_db($item_number, $item_description);
```

You'll need to change your code to handle the processing of an array of items:

```
$item_numbers = $_POST['item_number'];
$item_descriptions = $_POST['item_description'];
// validate that count($item_numbers) == count($item_descriptions)
for ($i = 0; $i < count($item_numbers); $i++) {
    add_item_to_db($item_numbers[$i], $item_descriptions[$i]);
}
```

There's quite a bit of error handling that you'll need to perform above that's not shown. If the user enters a different number of item_numbers than item_descriptions, you'll have to determine how to handle that. Also, any of the fields may be blank. Some cases may be errors, others perhaps not.

You'll have to change your HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="item_number[]" />
<input type="text" name="item_description[]" />
```

Note the *[]* in the name. That specifies an array of values for each.

Finally, you'll need to dynamically add a new set of *input* items on the screen when the user presses the *Add another item* link. I would recommend using jQuery for this. To accomplish this you would do something like:

```
jQuery('<input type="text" name="item_number[]" /><input type="text" name="item_description[]" />').appendTo('#someDiv');
```

Ensure that the new *input* elements are appended inside the form element. Obviously, there is a lot of code left to be written. This is just a basic example of the concepts.